# .htaccess 301 and PHP query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm wondering if the wonderful world of the SO community can help me with this one.

I have the following URL's that I would like to redirect/rewrite in my `.htaccess` file.

### 1. Redirect

I am trying to 301 redirect this URL:

```
http://example.com/staff-view.php?i=ACCOUNT_ID_EXAMPLE
```

to

```
http://example.com/staff-view/ACCOUNT_ID_EXAMPLE/
```

I have attempted the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+staff-view\.php\?i=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /staff-view/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

however when navigating to the from URL it does not redirect.

### 2. PHP Query String

I am using the below to rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^staff-view/([^/]+)/?$ /staff-view.php?i=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and accessing through URL

```
http://example.com/staff-view/ACCOUNT_ID_EXAMPLE/
```

it correctly directs me to the right page, but when attempting to access `ACCOUNT_ID_EXAMPLE` via the following methods:

```
<?
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

They both are empty:

```
array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

I would appreciate any help, if you need any more info, please let me know.

---

### Update 1

Updated `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^staff/([^/]+)/?$ /staff-view.php?i=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteBase "/"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^staff-view\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^i=([A-Z0-9_]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  ^staff/%1/
```

I have attempted to access the file from:

```
http://example.com/path/to/site/staff/ACCOUNT_ID
```

and it DOES NOT work. However, if I access the file from:

```
http://example2.com/staff/ACCOUNT_ID
```

it WORKS.

But if I go to `http://example2.com/staff-view.php?i=ACCOUNT_ID` it does not redirect to `http://example2.com/staff/ACCOUNT_ID` - this is not the end of the world, but I would like to fix it, but the deep directory issue as a priority `:)`.

Comment: Both your `RewriteRule` have the `L` flag which means stop processing. In addition, they seem circular (one redirects to the other, and the other redirects to the one).  Could that be part of the problem? Do things work any better if you rename `staff-view.php` to something else and redirect path `staff-view/id/` to it?  Then when I request `staff-view.php?id=1`, I'll be directed to `staff-view/1/` (with a `R=301`), then to `new-file.php?id=1` (silently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to parse `%{THE_REQUEST}` (e.g., "GET /staff-view.php?i=account_id HTTP/1.1") to extract both the path and the query string could work but it's unnecessarily complex.  I think it's much simpler to use two rewrite conditions that take advantage of the server variables `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `%{QUERY_STRING}` because they are pre-populated with the info you're interested in.

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

#If you don't have this set in your htaccess, 
#  Apache may prepend the final path with your on disk dir structure
RewriteBase "/"

#Rewrite if the /staff-view.php page is requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/staff-view\.php$

#Rewrite if the query string contains i parameter anywhere. Assumes
#  ID can be only digits; include all allowed chars. eg: [a-zA-Z0-9_]    
#Don't forget the '&' before {{QUERY_STRING}} otherwise the match
#  will fail if i is the first parameter
RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING} &i=([0-9]+)

#Rewrite the account ID as part of the path. Append the query string
#  in order to preserve other query parameters (eg: if user asked for
#  /staff-view.php?i=123&x=boo, you want to preserve x=boo.  a 301
#  redirect tells the browser to go to the new path and to remember it
#This will stop processing and cause the browser to make a new request
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /staff-view/%1/ [QSA,R=301,L]

#Finally, we want to silently forward any request matching the last
#  redirect target to the actual file that will serve the request. 
#  The account ID should be of the same format as above: ([0-9]+).  The
#  [L] flag tells the server to stop looking for new instructions
RewriteRule ^staff-view/([0-9]+)/$ /final.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The logic is easy to follow: If the path requested is `/staff-view.php`, and if the query string contains the `i` parameter, tell the user's browser to go instead to `/staff-view/ID`, preserving the other query params. Finally, when the browser asks for this new path, silently (without telling the browser) forward the request to `final.php` along with the ID and other query params

Comment: After finding the RCA of the 500 error, it is still not redirecting or outputting the query string :(

Comment: Made a suggestion under your Q. Could you test after renaming the final destination something other than `staff-view.php`?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion by "attempting" to direct `/staff/ID` to `staff-view.php`. Still not doing it.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the `/staff-view/ID` path; I meant to rename `staff-view.php`, adjust the rule under your Point #2 to point to the new name,  and still try to access the content at the old URLs (`staff-view.php?id=1` and `staff-view/ID`)

Comment: Correction, I think I have just found the problem for issue #2. If I try to access the file from a directory like this: `/path/to/site/dir/staff/ACCOUNT_ID`, PHP can't find the variables and it doesn't work. If I access it from `http://example.com/staff/ACCOUNT_ID` it works and PHP returns the details.

Comment: I have added details to my Q to clarify.

Comment: Let's rewind. There were 2 errors in my rules that I've changed. My first `RewriteCond` has been changed: I've inserted a `/` between `^` and `staff-view`.  In addition, my `RewriteRule` has also been changed to remove `^` that was before `staff`.  Please try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115055/discussion-between-david-passmore-and-patrick).

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^staff-view/([^/]*)$ /staff-view.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried it, but it is still not returning the query string for `ACCOUNT_ID_EXAMPLE`